# How to solve the WHERE clause problems?

Tags: where-clause

What is the problem in the below query?

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    start_station_name
FROM
    bigquery-public-data.london_bicycles.cycle_hire 
LIMIT 1000
WHERE  
    bike_id = 1710;
```

When I write the clause I get this error:

> Syntax error: Expected end of input but got keyword WHERE at [5:1]

How can I avoid this problem?

Comment: Possibly that LIMIT should be the final clause

Answer (score 1):

The statement `LIMIT` must be mentioned last.

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    start_station_name
FROM
    bigquery-public-data.london_bicycles.cycle_hire
WHERE  
    bike_id = 1710
LIMIT 1000;
```

[image]

ref: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_top.asp